# jquery slideshow fadeIn and fadeOut with interval

Tags: jquery, image, fade

I'm looking for plugin / script that makes some images animate with fadeIn and fadeOut. When an image fadesOut, the next image start to fadeIn after 3 sec. There will be 3 seconds that any image is visible. I tried with [caroufredsel](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/) but I had problem with IE8.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cycle pluggin will handle this. You have nearly 20 effects other than FadeIn if you wish to change the effect.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

code is simple as this

```
$('#s4').cycle({ 
    fx:      'scrollDown', 
    speed:    300, 
    timeout:  2000 
});
```

The speed option defines the number of milliseconds it will take to transition from one slide to the next. The timeout option specifies how many milliseconds will elapse between the start of each transition.

Comment: thanks. I tried this plugin. But How can I set the time when there's no image.  $('#s3').cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
  speed: 2500,
  sync: 0,
 });

Comment: what you want to do if there is no image ?

Comment: setting an interval between each image

Comment: timeout its a property that defines how long the image is visible. I'm looking for a property the defines the time between the end of an image and the beginning of the next one